# Batch equivalent of a shell script --> status="$(ps aux | grep process_name | grep -v grep)"

Tags: shell, batch-file

In *NIX systems you can get the information of a given `process_name` with:

```
status="$(ps aux | grep process_name | grep -v grep)"
```

What is the equivalent in batch?

I know the equivalent of `grep` in batch is `FNDSTR`, but how do I pipe line the commands and store the result into a variable?

Comment: first i'm listing all the processes using PS then finding only "process_name". In that grep process also got listed so i'm removing that one!

Comment: You should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The better you phrase your question, the more likely it is to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('qprocess ^| find /i "process_name"') do set "status=%%a"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tasklist /im processname.exe | findstr /v /i /c:"grep"
```

is one way. Tasklist can do it's own filtering, and also has filter sub command (`/fi "status eq running"`) . Not sure of your search for grep as it seem reduntant.